# HTTR GET works in browser, but fails in RStudio

Tags: r, json, api, httr

**Background:**

I'm using the code below to get a zipped file containing some XML-documents. A note on reproducibility; the endpoint is IP-restricted as well, so you won't be able to request anything from it (it'll just time out).

```
GET("https://dpsv3.doffin.no/Doffin/notices/Download/2020-07-17",
    authenticate(user, passwd),
    accept = "application/zip")
```

Using this from R; I get a 403 Access denied. If I use the same in Postman, I get the file. If I go to https://dpsv3.doffin.no/Doffin/notices/Download/2020-07-17 in a browser, I get a user/pass prompt and once entered, I get the file.

**Questions**

Is there anything wrong with my code? From what I gather, it should work, and similar code work with other APIs. Using the same code towards the test environment works; and if I enter the wrong password for the test environment, I get a 401 error instead. From this I gather that the authenticate part of my call isn't processed at the endpoint, but I can't spot any errors here. Any input?

Comment: I'd guess Postman in your browser is also passing along some authentication cookie that was set when you entered your username and password. Hard to say since the link does nothing for me. There are many different ways to authenticate to a website and the `authenticate()` by default uses "basic" authentication. Is there any documentation on what the website actually uses?

Comment: It is using basic.

Answer (score 1):

Soo, I think I found the problem. Changing my code to the following works:

```
GET("https://dpsv3.doffin.no/Doffin/notices/Download/2020-07-21",
    authenticate(user, passwd),
    accept = "application/zip",
    user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"))
```

I'm not sure why, but I guess there might be limitations on the endpoint? In either case; it works so I am happy.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to find a solution, it worked locally but not on RStudio Cloud. That last line of code saved me!